# C++ Why am I recieving the error redefinition of class?

Tags: c++, class, header-files

Below are two files, one contains the main functions and the other the h file

main

```
class issuesofRelevance{

public:
     vector<string> issues;
     int significance = 0; //initalize 0
     int approach = 0; //initalize 0

     issuesofRelevance() {

     }

     void setStance(vector<string> issues, int significance, int approach){

      std::random_device random_device; 
      std::default_random_engine generator(random_device());
      std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0,1);

     }

};
```

h file

```
class  issuesofRelevance
{
  public:
     std::vector<std::string> issues;
     int significance;
     int approach;

     issuesofRelevance(){}

  public:
  void setStance(std::vector<std::string> issues, int significance, int approach){}

};
```

When i attempt to compile these 2 files i get the error

```
 error: redefinition of ‘class issuesofRelevance’
 class issuesofRelevance{
```

Im unsure as to why this is occuring

Comment: You don't have to re-define `class  issuesofRelevance` in `.cpp`. Simply include the header.

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: `#include "*.h"` and if you need the class to be declared, simply write `class issuesofRelevance;` where you need it.

Comment: Why did you delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61954649/4386278) after somebody had gone to the trouble of answering it for you? That's not very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the main function is in `main.cpp` and the class is in `IssuesofRelevance.h`. You didn't mention anything about if you included the .h file in your .cpp file. But I am assuming that you did. So I am assuming you wrote

```
#include "IssuesofRelevance.h"
```

At the top of the main.cpp function. Now, what `#include` directive does, it takes the content of the included file, and copy pastes it in to the `main.cpp` file. Now you see, you have a class declaration in `IssuesofRelevance.h` file which is copy pasted in the `main.cpp`. Also, you have the same declaration in `main.cpp` file. So the compiler is seeing that you are declaring two classes having same names. Which is not allowed.

So if the two classes are the same then cut the one in `main.cpp` to the `IssuesofRelevance.h` and just go with including the .h file in the `main.cpp`. Everything should be fine.

Though in this way it will work. But, you might want a separate `.h` file and `.cpp` file for your class. The `.h` file contains the declaration. Declaration means the class' member variable and method signatures. And `.cpp` file will contain the method bodies. I think you wrote the definition in `main.cpp` file. You can do the declaration in the following way.

**issuesofRelevance.h**

```
class  issuesofRelevance
{
  public:
     std::vector<std::string> issues;
     int significance;
     int approach;

     issuesofRelevance();

  public:
  void setStance(std::vector<std::string> issues, int significance, int approach);

};
```

**issuesOfRelevance.cpp**

```
#include "issuesofRelevance.h"

issuesofRelevance::issuesofRelevance(){
}

void issuesofRelevance :: setStance(std::vector<std::string> issues, int significance, int approach){
    std::random_device random_device; 
      std::default_random_engine generator(random_device());
      std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your class along with relevant code you desire in a header file (`.h` extension, and easily configurable in workspace by an editor such as Visual Studio), and call it as in when required, using `#include"filename.h"`.

Note that header files are basically chunks of code copy-pasted into the source file and so if they include different definitions of the same function or say class for your case, it will result in ambiguity and throw an error - which is the situation in this scenario for your class `issueofRelevance`.

Corresponding compiling & linking errors:

If you write two same class definitions together in a file, then it will throw up an error due to the arising ambiguity which is detected by the **compiler**, since its only in a single file.

But when you place those two same definitions in different files and import them into your `cpp` file twice (or say you import them in another `cpp` file and build the solution like in visual studio) it will throw up a linker error as the **linker** is involved (multiple files - wherein the job of the linker is to link them into a combined executable) and it cannot select multiple definitions present in different files.

If your dealing with functions, then a solution to resolve that is to make the functions static, so that they are defined internally or only for the file they are being compiled against. This makes it possible to have multiple function definitions of the same function in different files with no linking error. Another option is to make it in-line.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the class **issuesofRelevance** twice so you got the compile error. You'd better define the class in one header file, and include it from other CPP file.
I have fixed your code and it's host online:

https://www.onlinegdb.com/ByuyF7BsL

It seems that you are new to c++, it's recommended to read some books like *c++ primer*